# Question on void **

Tags: c

```
int size=2;
char *a0;
char **allargs;
short *a1;
void **args;
allargs=(char **)malloc(size*sizeof(char *));
allargs[0]="a";
allargs[1]="100";
args=(void **)malloc(size*sizeof(void *));

a0 = malloc(sizeof(char *));
*a0=(*allargs[0]);
args[0]=(void *)&a0;
fprintf(stderr,"assigned %c %c\n",*a0,*((char *)args[0]));

a1 = malloc(sizeof(short *));
*a1=atoi(allargs[1]);
args[1]=(void *)&a1;
fprintf(stderr,"assigned %d %d \n",*a1,*((int *)args[1]));
```

for some reason i am getting the following for the output

assigned a  (should be a a )

assigned 100 166696 (should be 100 100)

Comment: Is this the real code ? You have at least one error in the code such that it shouldn't even compile as it is.

Comment: a0 = malloc(sizeof(char *));
really? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast args[0] and args[1] to char** and int**.

```
fprintf(stderr,"assigned %c %c\n",*a0,**((char **)args[0]));
fprintf(stderr,"assigned %d %d \n",*a1,**((int **)args[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you take the address of `a0` and `a1` to fill in `args`, you're getting a double-pointer.  When you calculate your output, you're only dereferencing once.  There are two ways that you can fix this to get the output you want.  You can change

```
args[0]=(void *)&a0;
```

to

```
args[0]=(void *)a0;
```

and change

```
args[1]=(void *)&a1;
```

to

```
args[1]=(void *)a1;
```

so that `args` contains single-pointers, **OR** you can change

```
fprintf(stderr,"assigned %c %c\n",*a0,*((char *)args[0]));
```

to

```
fprintf(stderr,"assigned %c %c\n",*a0,**((char **)args[0]));
```

and change

```
fprintf(stderr,"assigned %d %d \n",*a1,*((int *)args[1]));
```

to

```
fprintf(stderr,"assigned %d %d \n",*a1,**((int **)args[1]));
```

to double-dereference `args` during display.